# Using a value as the title of another table -- is this bad practice?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have the following table:

```
Table: Residents

ID   Name    Species
-------------------
1    Bob      Human
2    Fluffy   Cat
3    Laura    Human
```

Depending on the species, I'd like to refer to a different table for additional info. The value given under the species column is the name of the corresponding table.

```
Table: Cat

id     owner_id    fur_color
----------------------------
2        1          white


Table: Human

id      email
---------------
1       bob@gmail.com
3       laura@gmail.com
```

Is it bad practice to do this? If so, what is the preferred way to do something similar?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? There's no way to join a column value to a table name.

Comment: Shouldn't the owner_id in the Cat table be `2` for Fluffy's fur color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes. As @barmar mentioned in his comment, there is no way to join a column value to a table name (outside of building queries dynamically with a scripting language such as PHP).

Take a few moments to analyze your tables and the relationships between them. Expanding from your example, there is a "many-to-one" relationship between people and pets/animals because people can have more than one animal, but animals can't have more than one owner. If animals can have more than one owner, you have a "many-to-many" relationship.

In schema terms, your schema might look like this at the most basic level:

**Residents**

- ID
- Name
- E-mail

**Animals**

- ID
- OwnerID (must match an ID from the Residents table)
- Name

From the looks of it, you'll have different types of animals that need different attributes (e.g. reptiles won't have a fur_color option). You can just add another table like @barmar suggested. I'd leave out the human attributes, though, and keep them with the Residents table.

**AnimalAttributes**

- ID
- AnimalID (must match an ID in the Animals table)
- Attribute
- Value

The only downside to this setup, however is that you have to be diligent and make sure attributes exist, e.g. you don't forget to create a record for fur_color for Fluffy.

If there is a many-to-many relationship between animals and people, you'll need an intermediary table and drop the OwnerID column from the Animals table.

**Ownership**

- ID
- OwnerID (must match an ID in the Residents table)
- AnimalID (must match an ID in the Animals table)

Answer (score 0):

it would be better to have a generic table of attributes and values:

Table: Attributes:

```
id  owner_id    attr    value
1   1           email   bob@gmail.com
2   3           email   laura@gmail.com
3   2           fur_color white
```